# Combining many vectors into one larger vector (in an automated way)

Tags: r, vector

I have a list of identifiers as follows:

```
url_num <- c('85054655', '85023543', '85001177', '84988480', '84978776', '84952756', '84940316', '84916976', '84901819', '84884081', '84862066', '84848942', '84820189', '84814935', '84808144')
```

And from each of these I'm creating a unique variable:

```
for (id in url_num){
  assign(paste('test_', id, sep = ""), FUNCTION GOES HERE)
}
```

This leaves me with my variables which are:

```
test_8505465, test_85023543, etc, etc
```

Each of them hold the correct output from the function (I've checked), however my next step is to combine them into one big vector which holds all of these created variables as a seperate element in the vector. This is easy enough via:

```
c(test_85054655,test_85023543,test_85001177,test_84988480,test_84978776,test_84952756,test_84940316,test_84916976,test_84901819,test_84884081,test_84862066,test_84848942,test_84820189,test_84814935,test_84808144)
```

However, as I update the original 'url_num' vector with new identifiers, I'd *also* have to come down to the above chunk and update this too!

**Surely there's a more automated way I can setup the above chunk?**

Maybe some sort of concat() function in the original for-loop which just adds each created variable straight into an empty vector right then and there?

So far I've just been trying to list all the variable names and somehow get the output to be in an acceptable format to get thrown straight into the c() function.

```
for (id in url_num){
  cat(as.name(paste('test_', id, ",", sep = "")))
}
```

...which results in:

```
test_85054655,test_85023543,test_85001177,test_84988480,test_84978776,test_84952756,test_84940316,test_84916976,test_84901819,test_84884081,test_84862066,test_84848942,test_84820189,test_84814935,test_84808144,
```

This is *close* to the output I'm looking for but because it's using the cat() function it's essentially a print statement and its output can't really get put anywhere. Not to mention I feel like this method I've attempted is wrong to begin with and there must be something simpler I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can give me!

Troy

Comment: What is the point of creating all those variables?  What is the final result which you want?

Comment: Can't you just do `paste0("test_", url_num)` to have your desired output ? All in all, assigning variables is usually not a good idea, you could keep all your stuff in a list or a dataframe

Comment: try `vector=ls(pattern="^test")`

Comment: Like FlorianGD said, just `paste0("test_", url_num)`. No need to use for loop or the assign function.